# Problema con mi ruta Route [facturas.obtenerproductos] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Genere mis Controllers, modelos y vistas con infyom y todo perfecto pero cuando creo una función y la llamo con un `route` en una vista me dice que no esta definida

tengo en mi fichero `web.php` la siguiente linea

```
Route::resource('facturas', 'FacturaController');
```

Y en la vista intento llamar a mi función `obtenerproductos` y nada

lo tengo implementado así `{{ route('facturas.obtenerproductos') }}`

el error es el siguiente:

> Route [facturas.obtenerproductos] not defined. (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\productos_ventas2\resources\views\facturas\create_venta.blade.php)

Comment: ¿ define la ruta `obtenerproductos`  en su `routes.php`? ¿Existe el método en el controlador?

Comment: public function obtenerproducto(){

        $clientes = Clientes::all();
        $productos = Producto::all();

        $factura = new Factura();

        return view('facturas.create_venta')->with('clientes', $clientes)->with('clientes', $clientes)->with('factura', $factura)->with('productos', $productos);
      
    }

Comment: Route::get('obtenerproducto', 'FacturaController@obtenerproducto');

Comment: Por favor utiliza el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/141958/edit) de su pregunta y añada la ruta tal cuál está actualmente , incluyendo el orden actual _(antes o después de resource)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se solucionaría simplemente con añadir el `name` a su ruta y poder llamarla luego desde la vista.

```
Route::get('obtenerproducto', 'FacturaController@obtenerproducto');
// agregar nombre
Route::get('obtenerproducto', 'FacturaController@obtenerproducto')
         ->name('facturas.obtenerproductos');//con este llamas en la vista
Route::resource('facturas', 'FacturaController');
```

> Se recomienda añadir la ruta con el método antes de la ruta
>   `resource`,

Comment: muchisimas gracias, problema resuelto, agradecido

Answer (score -1):

Hola si ustedes están utilizando Jetstream y tienen la siguiente ruta desde la carpeta web.php:

```php
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function () {
  Route::get('/producto', ProductoController::class);
  Route::get('/dashboard', function(){
    return view('dashboard');
  })->name('dashboard');
});
```

Y les salta el error:

[image: Route [producto.index] not defined. (View:]

Solo agreguen esta línea de código:

```php
Route::get('/producto', ProductoController::class)->name('producto.index');
```

Y listo problema resuelto créditos a la primer respuesta.